# SEP firewall rule import via .xml ?

Tags: xml, windows-firewall, rules, sep

I've got a Windows Firewall rule defined like below table

<kbd>Name</kbd><kbd>Group</kbd><kbd>Profile</kbd><kbd>Enabled</kbd><kbd>Action</kbd><kbd>Program</kbd><kbd>Local Address</kbd><kbd>Remote Address</kbd><kbd>Protocol</kbd><kbd>Local Port</kbd><kbd>Remote Port</kbd><kbd>Allowed Computers</kbd>

<kbd>SpotifyRuleOutbound</kbd>             <kbd>Domain, Private</kbd>      <kbd>Yes</kbd>      <kbd>Block</kbd>      <kbd>C:\Users\a....\spotify.exe</kbd>      <kbd>Any</kbd>      <kbd>Any</kbd>      <kbd>Any</kbd>      <kbd>Any</kbd>      <kbd>Any</kbd>      <kbd>Any</kbd>

What I want to do is adding this same rule for inbound and outbound in the "Symantec Endpoint Protection" firewall using the `smc -importadvrule` command with a .sar or .xml file. How the file should look like?

Answer (score 0):

You can't import SEP firewall rule with .xml format.